# Searchable pandas release notes

Tags: python, pandas, python-packaging, changelog

I know that the pandas release notes can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html

However, these are next to useless for me because they are not easily searchable. I need to figure out which features were removed/added in which version of Pandas, to help create requirements/dependency lists for python packages. Does a full single text file change log exist somewhere, so that I can search changes across all versions?

Comment: Great question.   I too liked the old HTML style where was one HTML with all the 'What's New?' for all versions.  Eventually, it would need to be broken up.  I've been reading the docs on this library fo the past six years, do you have an specific methods in mind?

Comment: For searching? Well if it was just one big text file in the git repo somewhere that would be great. But I checked in the repo and the release notes file there just points to the web version. Or, yeah, one html page somewhere would also be fine.

Comment: Probably pdf version could be useful (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/pandas.pdf), but parsing it would be a bit more difficult.

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina oh nice, not perfect but still pretty good! PDF search tools can pick up e.g. "Panel4D" and then I easily find that it was removed in version 0.23.